# Regex expression to remove start to end of character in string

Tags: javascript, regex, substring, splice

I have this string:

```
var string = "From: Jeremy<br />
 Sent: 22 Apr 2016 12:08:03</br />
 To: Mark<br />
 Subject: Another test email<br /><br />

 Hi Mark, 
<br />
I'm sending this email as a way to test the email! 
<br />
Cheers, 
<br />
Jeremy"
```

And I would like to splice this string from the start until after the "Subject" line so I get the email body content.

I've tried this so far:

```
string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('Subject'), string.length - 1)
```

But this option does return the Subject line as well from the string.

Is there a regex library I can use?

Comment: You know you cant spread a string across multiple lines in JS without concatenating with a `+` right? Just formatted like that for SO?

Comment: @annOnC0d3r yes, this is just the returned string from the database. Just used it as an example for clarity. Thanks for comment though, helps me improve on the way I express my code/questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `string.replace` you can do:

```
var body = string.replace(/^[\s\S]*\s+Subject: [^\n]*\n+/, '')
```

**Code:**

```js
var string = `From: Jeremy<br />
Sent: 22 Apr 2016 12:08:03</br />
To: Mark<br />
Subject: Another test email<br /><br />

Hi Mark, 
<br />
I'm sending this email as a way to test the email! 
<br />
Cheers, 
<br />
Jeremy`

var body = string.replace(/^[\s\S]*\s+Subject: [^\n]*\n+/, '')

document.writeln("<pre>" + body + "</pre>")
```

`[\s\S]*` matches 0 or more of any characters including newline. It is followed by `Subject:` line which is also removed.

**Output:**

```
"Hi Mark, 
<br />
I'm sending this email as a way to test the email! 
<br />
Cheers, 
<br />
Jeremy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone will give you the non-regex solution, but here is one with regex

```
[\s\S]*Subject\s*:.*([\s\S]+) <-- your result in first capturing group
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD6gA2/2)**

*JS Demo*

```js
var re = /[\s\S]*Subject\s*:.*([\s\S]+)/gm; 
var str = `From: Jeremy<br />
Sent: 22 Apr 2016 12:08:03</br />
To: Mark<br />
Subject: Another test email<br /><br />

Hi Mark, 
<br />
I'm sending this email as a way to test the email! 
<br />
Cheers, 
<br />
Jeremy`
var m = re.exec(str);
document.writeln("<pre>" + m[1] + "</pre>");
```

Comment: copied some part(not regex) from @anubhava

Comment: indeed this example provides the solution I need! thanks